# WindowBuilder ImageIcon

Tags: java, eclipse, imageicon, windowbuilder

Just a rather simple step but I can't get it done.

A code like this:

```
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon ("abc.JPG"));
```

Problem:
ImageIcon cannot be resolved to a type

What's wrong there? Is there any libraries or configuration that I missed out?

Comment: Have you tried `new javax.swing.ImageIcon(...)` or importing `javax.swing.ImageIcon`

Comment: Thanks guys!! I just found out that I didn't import it... >.<